# Append Element Into Element

Tags: javascript, html

It might sound stupid , but i didn't find the correct way to achieve this . I want to create an element(in our example a div element) and add to it the textarea value . In my example it seems that the element is created but i cant embed it into the #notesPosition . I achieve this with JQuery but i`am not sure whats the best way to do it with pure Javascript.

```js
var notesPositionToAdd = document.getElementById('notesPosition');
var notesTextareaBtn = document.getElementById('btnAddNotes');


notesTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var notesTextarea = document.getElementById('addNotesTextarea').value;
  console.log(notesTextarea);
  var newEl = document.createElement('div');


  newEl.append(notesTextarea);
  newEl.className += " col-lg-2";
  console.log(newEl);



});
```

```html
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 offset-md-8 ">
    <form id="newNoteForm">
      <div class="form-group offset-lg-6">
        <i class="fa fa-times text-md-right " aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <label for="addNotesTextarea">Add notes !</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="addNotesTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" value="Add" id="btnAddNotes">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="notesPosition">

</div>
```

Comment: where do you want to put the new div?

Comment: you can use appendChild(newEl);

Comment: You mean `document.getElementById('notesPosition').appendChild(newEl);`?

Comment: @KristjanKica it doesnt work

Comment: @j08691 It seems that i tried appendChild but i was getting an error .

Comment: Worked for me. What error did you get? https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/753pf0ps/

Comment: this is so strange , when i used appendChild i was getting an error

Comment: where do you want to put the new div?

Comment: seriously i was like an hour trying with appendChild and i was getting an error about incorrect Node

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>  here is there error iam getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello

Check if this helps:

```
newEl.append(notesTextarea);
newEl.className += " col-lg-2";
console.log(newEl);
```

to:

```
newEl.append(notesTextarea);
newEl.className += " col-lg-2";  
notesPositionToAdd.append(newEl);
console.log(newEl);
```

I hope it helped you!

Comment: thank you for you answer , this is stupid maybe my brain spinning , i tried the append() method to insert my created div into the  notesPositionToAdd and appendChild as well and none of them worked thats why i asked for help . Maybe it was my browser cache or something . this is really weird .

Comment: `.append()` is experimental at the moment. Better to use `.appendChild()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: @j08691 yeah saw that mate  , thank you for mention it .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `addTextNode()` then you can...

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var txt = document.createTextNode('Whatever Text');
    div.appendChild(txt);
```

alternatively

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = 'Whatever Text' // Whatever text parsed, <p>Words</p> is OK
```

alternatively

```
var div - document.createElement('div')
    div.textContent = 'Whatever' // Not parsed as HTML
```